How to construct input of rust program that is fed into solana rbpf?
Get hello.o
anchor init hello
anchor build

lib.rs
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("3bKgMxR7MwXLzGDfdsW8HsNYSSxRejf6uUF69Mmupfx7");

#[program]
pub mod hello {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Greetings from: {:?}", ctx.program_id);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}


Construct input
The input is the encoding of the function initialize
input
WPNHsFPyEMr

Run in rbpf
./rbpf/cli/target/debug/rbpf_cli -u jit --mem 9999999999 --input ./solidity/sol/input --elf ./solidity/sol/hello.so --trace

memory: [87, 80, 78, 72, 115, 70, 80, 121, 69, 77, 114]
Result: Err(UnsupportedInstruction)
Instruction Count: 1377
Trace:


